# Why does pressing login redirect to register page and show MultivalueDictError in Django?

Tags: python, django

```
def login(request):
if request.method == 'POST':

    username = request.POST['username']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(request,user)
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        messages.info(request , 'Credentials not correct')
        return redirect('login')

return render(request,'login.html')
```

i dont know why when i press login it redirect to register and show multivaluedicterror. even i have not redirected to register page in code

[login.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6p9O.png)
[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugGMd.png)

Comment: Indentation isn't correct.

Comment: thanks for reply indentations are correct i have fixed it the problem is in html file in <form    method="POST" action="register"> action is overwriting the code i just removed it <form  method="POST"> and it fixed the problem